# left/right/inner join on mysql statement

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL query :

```
SELECT band.id bid, band.name, bandInfo.summary, bandImage.url bandImage, 
user.username, user.online, userImage.url userImage
FROM bands AS band
INNER JOIN band_info AS bandInfo ON band.id = bandInfo.bid
LEFT JOIN band_images AS bandImage ON band.id = bandImage.bid
LEFT JOIN band_followers AS follower ON follower.bid = band.id
RIGHT JOIN users AS user ON user.id = follower.uid
INNER JOIN user_info AS userInfo ON userInfo.uid = user.id
LEFT JOIN user_images AS userImage ON user.id = userImage.uid
WHERE ((band.activated = 1) AND (user.activated = 1)) AND (bandInfo.language = 'fr')
ORDER BY band.name
```

'users' table contains all users (one row = one user)

'user_info' table contains all info about an user (one row = one user)

'user_images' table contains all image about users (one row = one user)

'bands' table contains all music bands (one row = one band)

'band_info' table contains all info about a band (multiple row for one band due to the language)

'band_images' table contains all image about bands (one row = one band)

'band_followers' table contains all relations between users and bands (one row = one relation so there are many row containing the same band id but not the same user id)

I would like to retrieve all bands with their info (INNER JOIN) EVEN IF the band id isn't in the band_followers table. I want to retrieve too all bands when the band id is in the band_followers table with an INNER JOIN on user id with the user's info (INNER JOIN) EVEN IF he doesn't have any image.

My problem is just the JOIN keyword.. I don't really know if I have to use LEFT or RIGHT JOIN

Thanks !

UPDATE ANSWER :

```
SELECT band.id bid, band.name, bandInfo.summary, bandImage.url bandImage, user.username, user.online, userImage.url userImage
FROM bands AS band
INNER JOIN band_info AS bandInfo ON band.id = bandInfo.bid
LEFT JOIN band_images AS bandImage ON band.id = bandImage.bid
LEFT JOIN band_followers AS follower ON band.id = follower.bid
LEFT JOIN users AS user ON user.id = follower.uid AND user.activated = 1
LEFT JOIN user_info AS userInfo ON userInfo.uid = user.id
LEFT JOIN user_images AS userImage ON user.id = userImage.uid
WHERE (band.activated = 1) AND (bandInfo.language = 'fr')
ORDER BY band.name
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `LEFT JOIN` before `users` and `user_info`, just like you do before `band_followers`. `LEFT JOIN` means to return all the rows of the previous tables even if they don't match anything in the table you're joining with. `RIGHT JOIN` means to return all rows of the table you're joining with. So if you use `RIGHT JOIN users`, you'll get all users, not just the users who are following the band.

You should also put the test `user.activated = 1` into the `ON` clause of `LEFT JOIN users`. Otherwise, you'll filter out all the bands that have no followers, because they don't have any followers with `user.activated`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: "left join" means take the left item and if there is a matching right one, attach it.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you have the statements like

> EVEN IF the band id isn't in the band_followers table.

OR

> EVEN IF he doesn't have any image

Try using a `OUTER JOIN` like either `LEFT OUTER JOIN` OR `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` per the your requirement.

Comment: That's what he's using. `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` are always outer joins, the word `OUTER` is optional.

Comment: @Barmar, yes true but I believe what OP is saying is that, he is confused whether he should use OUTER/INNER join. That's what I am trying to point out in answer.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your answer, I thought you were just telling him to change `LEFT JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

this question might help you out [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

but the best answer there was this picture (in my opinion)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UKp7.png